# "Scheiße ist Bargeld"

Tags: slang, idiom, english-to-german

I know the title is a bit rude, but that's exactly what my question is about. The title is what Google Translate [recommends](http://translate.google.com/#en%7Cde%7Cshit%20is%20cash) as the German equivalent of "shit is cash".

I've often seen the expression "shit is cash" on some English-speaking sites. I know what it means, but I cannot form words to describe. So, my problem is, how would you translate this to German?

Comment: I don't know why Gigili edited my question, but in this way it seems like I actually value the result Google gives for this translation.

Comment: Sorry about the edit but your sentence was wrong. I don't know if I've emphasized the google result but you did when it's your title!

Comment: Can you give some examples, where 'shit is cash' is used?

Comment: see below in the accepted answer, i knew it was often used in memes, but not that it seems to originate from those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would translate this to *"geiler Scheiß"*: This preserves the rude language quite well and has also the positive connotation.
As a sidenote: The internet-meme "shit was so cash" (as explained [here](http://ohinternet.com/So_cash)) is sometimes (jokingly) translated literally to "Scheiße war so Bargeld".

Answer (score 6):

In vulgar colloquial German two related sayings come to mind:

- *["Aus Scheiße Geld machen"](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~aus%20Scheisse%20Geld%20machen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)* - to make a lot of money from sth. worthless
- *["der Geldscheißer"](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/worte-der-woche-hoeness-und-die-geldscheisser-1.441038)* - a fictional person that gives you all the money you need (*Uncle Scrooge*)

In German both expressions have a slightly different meaning as compared to the Endlish expression but this also depends on the context.

Comment: It's "Aus Scheiße Geld or Gold machen" but "Geldscheißer" is correct but not used, we use "Goldesel" :-)

Comment: full ack: we don't use these expressions here either. *"Goldesel"* is definitely a good non-vulgar alternative - but the question was on vulgar slang as far as I can see...

Comment: Are you referring to Dagobert Duck? If yes, I'd suggest to use his english name while speaking english, Scrooge McDuck, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think neither expression fits. For me, "shit is cash" means to describe something that's "as great as money can't buy". At least that's what I always thought it meant.

Comment: I don't know of *Geldscheißer* as a person, only the *Esel* from the legend.

Comment: There is also *Dukatenkacker*.

Comment: If you know Uncle Scrooge you know it's wrong to think he will give you any money!